# What is the effect that cooked sieved egg yolks added to pastry dough will have on the final product?

Tags: eggs, cookies, pastry, tenderizing

I have heard that this will create a more tender end product.

Comment: What pastry dough, there are several types? What are you making from it? And more tender compared to what, no egg whatsoever, or raw egg, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

I have seen some blogs (without any references) that some old European recipes utilise hard boiled eggs, for Cakes & Sablé.  It is mentioned that it is used to reduce the gluten binding together too much.  I would guess it works similarly to gnocchi, the quantity of mashed potato mixed in the flour reduces the gluten leaving a soft pillowy texture.

Comment: Interesting!  If you can point out which blogs, or which recipes, that would be helpful - even if the blogs themselves don't give the original references.

Comment: Here is a recipe from the great Pierre Herme. The blogger describes a texture which is not like shortbread, but that has a delightfully crumbly snap. http://www.atkokken.com/2011/06/06/pierre-hermes-sable-a-lolive-noir-recipe-black-olive-cookies-recipe/